# Call an old C++ function from .NET for non-primitive data type

Tags: .net, interop

I have an old C++ function that I must use in my .NET application. Every time I tried to call and cast the pointer back to the class, I receive an error indicating that I attempted to read or write into protected memory. Could someone help me to point me to the right direction please. Here's the codes:

```
typedef struct
{
 char szModel[32];
 float fSpeed;
 float fData[20];
} CAR, far *LP_CAR; 

//Function prototype
int FAR PASCAL Process(char szModel[32], LP_DATA pCar);
```

And my .NET codes:

```
[DllImport("Unmanaged.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int Process(string model, IntPtr data);

//****** Implementation **********

public class ManagedClass
{
   public string szModel = new string(new char[32]);
   public float fSpeed;
   public float[] fData = new float[20];
}

ManagedClass aCar = new ManagedClass();
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.Sizeof(aCar));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(aCar, ptr, false);
Process(aCar, ptr);

ManagedClass model2 = (ManagedClass)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, 
                                                           typeof(ManagedClass));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

C++

```
typedef struct
{
  char szModel[32];
  float fSpeed;
  float fData[20];
} CAR, far *LP_CAR; 

extern "C" {
    int __stdcall Process(char *szModel, CAR &lpCar); 
}
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct CAR
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szModel;
    float fSpeed;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    float[] fData;
}

[DllImport("Unmanaged.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern int Process(
    string model, 
    ref CAR data
);
```

Call it as follows:

```
CAR data;
Process(@"test", ref data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your "CAR" ManagedClass structure like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct CAR
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr, SizeConst=32)]
    public string szModel;
    float fSpeed;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=20, MarshalTypeRef=typeof(float[]))]
    float[] fData;
}
```

Then invoke your native method with:

```
CAR myCar;

Process( model, ref myCar );
```

Comment: //The following compiles, but it gives only zero and empty string:[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]public class ManagedClass { [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)] public char[] szModel; public float fSpeed; public float[] fData = new float[20]; }

Comment: You're still using "class" instead of "struct" on ManagedClass. The the char[] should be changed to string as the framework marshaling attributes will take care of the conversion for you. Also, the fData array should probably be marshaled by the framework as well.

Comment: The framework cannot marshal correctly as there are more arrays in the class. I have to use "class", not struct.

Comment: You don't need to use the "Marshal" class. That's why you're passing "myCar" by reference.